# Unexpected token error in Express controller

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to run this small piece of code, but it is giving me a very weird issue.

```
    "use strict";

    module.exports = app => {
        let validator = app.validators.internalProductValidator;
        let internalProductService = app.services.internalProductService;
        let bitlyService = app.services.bitlyService;
        let feedbackSettingService = app.services.feedbackSettingService;

    function createEntity (req, res, next) {
        console.log(feedbackSettingService);
         feedbackSettingService.getUrl(data)
            .then((data)) => bitlyService.shortenLink(data))
            .then((data) => internalProductService.saveInternalProductRequest(data))
            .then(data => res.send(data))
            .catch(err => next(err));
    }

    return {
        createEntity
    };
};
```

When I print `console.log(feedbackSettingService)`, it works fine.

I get this error when I run `npm start`:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/controllers/internalProductController.js:15
         feedbackSettingService.getUrl(data)
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I am using consign to autoload scripts.

Comment: [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: It says parsing error. But, where exactly is the error?

Comment: `.then((data)) => bitlyService.shortenLink(data))`. Count the parentheses.

Comment: Ooohh. Serious mistake. Thanks a lot.